# AbsListView showing in logcat slowing down loading of ListActivity when loading first time on samsung device

Tags: android, performance, listview

I have a ListActivity that takes a long time to load when it's first loaded after the phone has turned on... but after having turned on the phone and the activity being loaded once there's no problem and it loads fast (even if I exit the app and start it again). The problem doesn't appear on my emulator however.
I did a comparison to the logcat outputs in both situations and the results are the following:

Below is the output when the ListActvity comes up with good speed (loaded once before when the phone was on)

```
04-29 21:09:59.676: D/AbsListView(5668): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-29 21:09:59.706: D/AbsListView(5668): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-29 21:09:59.706: D/AbsListView(5668): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 21:09:59.726: D/AbsListView(5668): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-29 21:09:59.726: D/AbsListView(5668): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 21:09:59.786: D/AbsListView(5668): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 21:09:59.896: D/AbsListView(5668): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 21:10:00.186: D/AbsListView(5668): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 21:10:00.196: I/TextToSpeech(5668): Sucessfully bound to com.samsung.SMT
04-29 21:10:00.196: I/TextToSpeech(5668): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.samsung.SMT/com.samsung.SMT.SamsungTTSService}
04-29 21:10:00.206: I/TextToSpeech(5668): Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.samsung.SMT/com.samsung.SMT.SamsungTTSService}
```

And this one is the output when it loads the first time after the phone is turned on (which is very slow):

```
04-29 20:37:57.189: D/AbsListView(5552): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-29 20:37:57.239: D/AbsListView(5552): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-29 20:37:57.239: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:57.239: D/AbsListView(5552): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-29 20:37:57.239: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:57.249: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(5552): successfully opened database Complete
04-29 20:37:57.349: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:57.399: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:57.409: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:57.409: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:57.589: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:59.559: D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-29 20:37:59.589: I/TextToSpeech(5552): Sucessfully bound to com.samsung.SMT
04-29 20:37:59.589: I/TextToSpeech(5552): Connected to  ComponentInfo{com.samsung.SMT/com.samsung.SMT.SamsungTTSService}
04-29 20:37:59.649: I/TextToSpeech(5552): Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.samsung.SMT/com.samsung.SMT.SamsungTTSService}
```

The difference is that when it loads the first time it opens the database and the

" D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called "

line gets called a few more extra times.
I'm pretty sure that the database openening doesn't cause the delay since it get's opened in other activities of the app as well and doesn't take time + plus the fact that it doesn't cause any delay on the emulator. So it's mostly the " D/AbsListView(5552): unregisterIRListener() is called " code getting called more times that's causing this issue on the samsung galaxy grand2 device.

I've also set the list view height to "match_parent".

Comment: Ideas:
1. Add the -vthreadtime flag to logcat, to get nice timestamps.
2. com.samsung.SMT seems to be some kind of text-to-speech service. Do you have this enabled in your device settings? Or does your app intentionally interact with it in some way? Maybe it takes time to initialize when starting for the first time after reboot.
3. Actually, run logcat like this: "adb logcat -bevents -bmain -bsystem -vthreadtime". That will include interesting system events, and should indicate whether the SMT stuff is being started during your activity launch (looking for the am_proc_start tag, for example).

Comment: Yes I'm using text to speech in the code it's a list view that contains a button that calls tts.speak when pressed and it's initialized as following in onCreate:Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
  checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
  startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE); How do I run your suggested adb command to filter the messages of my app?

Comment: I forgot to paste the onResult code for tts initialization:if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {

   if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
    // success, create the TTS instance
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    myc2.setTtsinclass(tts);
   }
   else {
    // missing data, install it
    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
    installIntent
      .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    startActivity(installIntent);
   }

Comment: I've changed the logcat outputs to include timestamps.

Comment: You can run adb through the command line/terminal/shell. The executable is found in the platform-tools folder under your Android SDK.